# How to pass variables from for loop to kwargs in pandas.df.apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I am having difficulty passing a variable to an argument using df.apply. I have a function which splits a string then counts how many substrings match items in a list. I am applying this to a pandas dataframe using apply to pass the string to be split and the list to look up matches in. This works if applied directly though fails if I try to pass this information in a for loop, the problem seems to be with the kwargs not accepting the variable.

Here is the example function

```
def classification_counter(original, class_lists):
          ...:     count=0
          ...:     for y in original.split():
          ...:         if y in class_lists:
          ...:             count= count+1
          ...:     return count
```

For example here are my lists which contain keywords I will later look for:

```
bikes = ['raleigh', 'trek', 'cannondale']
cars = ['ford', 'bmw', 'vw']
```

The list I will loop through:

```
class_set = ['cars', 'bikes']
```

This is my dataframe:

```
In [116]: df
Out[116]: 
   bikes  cars                               texts
0      0     0              I like to drive my bmw
1      0     0        I like to ride my cannondale
2      0     0   I keep my trek on a rack on my vw
0      0     0  my wifes car is a vw mine is a bmw
```

If I use apply to a column it works as expected:

```
In [119]:  df['cars']=df['texts'].apply(classification_counter, class_lists=cars)   

In [121]:  df['bikes']=df['texts'].apply(classification_counter, class_lists=bikes)    

In [122]: df
Out[122]: 
   bikes  cars                               texts
0      0     1              I like to drive my bmw
1      1     0        I like to ride my cannondale
2      1     1   I keep my trek on a rack on my vw
0      0     2  my wifes car is a vw mine is a bmw
```

However if I try to loop through my list it breaks:

```
In [117]: for x in class_set:
      ...:     df[x]=df['texts'].apply(classification_counter, class_lists=x)
     ...:     

In [118]: df
Out[118]: 
   bikes  cars                               texts
0      0     0              I like to drive my bmw
1      0     0        I like to ride my cannondale
2      0     1   I keep my trek on a rack on my vw
0      0     3  my wifes car is a vw mine is a bmw
```

Am I missing something regarding the correct way to pass a variable to a keyword argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to write your own "complicated" function for this. Use pandas [`Series.str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) for this:

```
for col in class_set:
    df[col] = df.texts.str.count('|'.join(eval(col)))

print(df)
   bikes  cars                               texts
0      0     1              I like to drive my bmw
1      1     0        I like to ride my cannondale
2      1     1   I keep my trek on a rack on my vw
3      0     2  my wifes car is a vw mine is a bmw
```

**To make your own code work**, use the following:

```
for x in class_set:
    df[x]=df['texts'].apply(classification_counter, class_lists=eval(x))
```

But in pandas you always want to use a vectorized solution, since it speeds your code up a lot compared to own defined functions and for loops.

**Edit for explanation**
We use `'|'.join` to make a string representation of the list:

```
bikes = ['raleigh', 'trek', 'cannondale']

print('|'.join(bikes))
raleigh|trek|cannondale
```

And we use `eval` since you cannot call your variable as a string, we have to use eval for that, since your `class_set` list cotnains of string. But we want to call the lists `bikes` and `car` and not the strings.

```
text = 'hello'

x = 'text'

print(eval(x))
hello
```

Comment: Ah nice usage of str.count and I really like the eval part

Comment: Thank you sir! @Wen-Ben

Comment: Thank you. This looks helpful, could you explain the ('|'.join(eval(col))) part?

Answer (score 1):

If that is what you need , you do not need build your own function look at `get_dummies`

```
bikesdict=dict.fromkeys(bikes,'bikes')
carsdict=dict.fromkeys(cars,'cars')
d={}
d.update(bikesdict)
d.update(carsdict)
df.texts.str.get_dummies(' ').groupby(by=d,axis=1).sum()
Out[344]: 
   bikes  cars
0      0     1
1      1     0
2      1     1
3      0     2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is that `x` in your for loop is a string. When you did apply for each column individually, you passed the lists `cars` and `bikes` as the keyword `class_lists`. In the for loop, however, you are passing the strings `'cars'` and `'bikes'` as the `class_lists` keyword.

It would work if you made a dictionary of your classes. That is,

```
class_dict = {'cars':['ford', 'bmw', 'vw'], 
             'bikes':['raleigh', 'trek', 'cannondale']}
```

and changed the for loop to:

```
>>> for k, v in class_dict.items():
...     df[k]=df['texts'].apply(classification_counter, class_lists=v)

>>> df

   bikes  cars                               texts
0      0     1              I like to drive my bmw
1      1     0        I like to ride my cannondale
2      1     1   I keep my trek on a rack on my vw
3      0     2  my wifes car is a vw mine is a bmw
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand that but I'm unsure how to pass the variable rather than the string?

Comment: Just edited. Haven't tested the solution yet, though!

Comment: Thank you I will test later.

Comment: Tested. I forgot to add the .items() iterator in the for loop originally. It's fixed now and it works.